# Writing audio device loopback on MacOS with Xamarin (C#)

Tags: macos, mono, core-audio, monomac

I am developing cross platform (Windows, Mac) desktop application that will be able to catch desktop sound. I already achieved this with NAudio on Widnows, but I have problems with OSX.

From what I have found, there is MonoMac implementation that have AudioUnit class that is able to catch sound recording, but due to lack of documentation and samples I am not able to determin wheather it works only for microphone or for whole desktop (loopback device).

Also I found that there is possibility of writing AudioDevice and AudioEngine (like in example from this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430235365), chapter 12), but it brings new problems like wrapping c++ to c#.

Is there any other better alternative? Or do I have to stick to finding that I already have? Can someone cast some light on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need something like [BASS Lib](http://www.un4seen.com), it's also cross platform.

Comment: Does it support loopback device, any examples? I tried on pc, but had some major problems with integration over mac. Dll did not work.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but you can see the specifications on their off site [link was in answer]